# Inter Cell Communication in UITableView/CollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, nsnotificationcenter

I have a UITableView with multiple cells of different types. These cells have attached classes to them, so all their events are handled by each of their own 'ViewModel' type classes, instead of at 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath'.

The challenge we have is that an event in one cell, might lead to a change in the some other cell. The question is, how do we facilitate this?

From the top of my head, I can think of multiple ways:

- NSNotificationCenter - pretty sure this will get ugly really quickly (plus the hassle of observing / and removing observation)
- passing a reference of the tableview to each of the cells, and making them call a tableView method like 'propogateEventToOtherCells:event'.

One thing that we have working in our favour is that the data/model for each of these cells is always in memory as an array (property of our tableView), irrespective of whether the cell is rendered or is in the viewport.

What approach can you guys think of to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you drawing the cells using `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or are the cells handling their own drawing code as well?

Comment: Do you also know the `NSIndexPath`s of the cells you would need to update, or is that calculated separately?

Comment: Is there a reason you want the cells to look after their own methods? How many rows are we talking about here?

Comment: please show some code

Comment: Have you ruled out simply sending `reloadData` to your tableView whenever an event in one cell occurs?

If so, and if you're reasonably certain that these cells will remain together in one tableview, I'd go the reference/delegate route.

OTOH, if it's likely they'll be in other, more disconnected places, or if the events triggering the redraws will have other sources than those sibling cells, I'd go with NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: @Ollie each of the cells are handling their own drawing internally.

Comment: Also, the table view can be setup such that it knows which indexPaths to update, cause it contains the initial model. But each of the cells won't know what other cells requiring an update are at what indexPaths.

Comment: @JohnnyRockex we're talking about 10-15 cells on an average. But the point is that these are complex cells, with different types of models, and views. So we want to separate the business logic and view layout code in each them to avoid our table view knowing too much about them, and hopefully avoid the massive view controller.

Comment: @Gereon the cells will always be in one table view at a time. Before I call reloadData, or reloadAtIndexPath, I want to modify the changed cells model first before I call reload. And what to change will come from the cell which emits the event.